# How to change the background color by the width of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

I'm trying to make a progress bar. The HTML is the following:

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width:5%"></div>
```

I want to paint the DIV's background according to the width of it. 
For example, if it is lower than 100 (the value returned is in px), I want it to be painted with red.

I've tryed the following:

```
var currentWidth = $('.progress-bar').width();
if (currentWidth < 100) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('background-color','red');
}
```

[Here is the demo on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ceHBT/)

But it is not painting it.

I'm not used to use javascript and jquery, so I believe it could be a syntax error or something I can't see. Can anyone help me how to make it work please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code looks fine as long it's inside document ready or after the elements in the DOM, but when exactly is this supposed to happen, on pageload only, or on some event or... ?

Comment: you need to set a height. otherwise it wont show

Comment: Looks fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/HxVNj/ Did you give it a height or add any content in it so it shows up. Are you calling it before it is rendered?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj6BB/
P.S: `Just added height.`

Comment: Have you seen the *progress* element?  http://html5doctor.com/the-progress-element/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using inline styles you can use the style property of the div to get the width in %

```
var currentWidth = $('.progress-bar')[0].style.width;
if (parseFloat(currentWidth, 10) < 100) {
    $('.progress-bar').css('background-color','red');
}
```

---

For multiple

```
$('.progress-bar').each(function(){
    var currentWidth = this.style.width;
    if (parseFloat(currentWidth, 10) < 11) {
        $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, but it is still not working. it is painting all the progress bars. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/uSSyx/

Comment: @LuAmbros I think you missed to add jQuery in the previous example

Comment: True, it s working here, thank you! http://jsfiddle.net/uSSyx/6/ I don't know how but it is not working online! Myabe because I'm with many progress bars...

Comment: do you have any ideia how can I do so I can apply automaticly to many progress bars? Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSSyx/7/

Comment: @Musa Thank you so much! I made the colors conditions based on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/uSSyx/30/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine.  only thing is specify `height`

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width:5%;height:5px"></div>
```

and you js should look lilke

```
$(function () {
    var currentWidth = $('.progress-bar').width();
    console.log(currentWidth);
    if (currentWidth < 100) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Gzw/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "manual" progress bar that you can increase by clicking a button to see how it changes color and size as it grows.  Just remove the button and place with in your loop to do the same thing automatically.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fdYJ8/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="progress-bar"></div>
<input type="button" id="increase" value="Increase" />
```

**CSS**

```
.progress-bar {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on("click", "#increase", function () {
    var currentWidth = $('.progress-bar').width();
    currentWidth += 5;
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', currentWidth + 'px');
    if (currentWidth < 100) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('background-color', 'red');
    } else if (currentWidth < 200) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } else {
        $('.progress-bar').css('background-color', 'green');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working you might need to put the code in `document.ready` and also put some text in div to see the result. Also make sure you incuded jQuery successfully.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ve4XH/)**

*Html*

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width:5%">123</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentWidth = $('.progress-bar').width();
    if (currentWidth < 100) {
        $('.progress-bar').css('background-color','red');
    }
});
```